# Scraping large amount of data with beautifulsoup, process being killed?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, memory-management

There are exactly 100 items per page. I'm assuming it is some type of memory limit that's causing it to be killed. Also I have a feeling appending the items to a list variable is most likely not best practice when it comes to memory efficiency. Would opening a text file and writing to it be better? I've done a test with 10 pages and it creates the list successfully taking about 12 seconds to do so. When I try with 9500 pages however, the process gets automatically killed in about an hour.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import timeit

def lol_scrape():
  start = timeit.default_timer()

  summoners_listed = []
  for i in range(9500):
    URL = "https://www.op.gg/leaderboards/tier?region=na&page="+str(i+1)
    user_agent = {user-agent}
    page = requests.get(URL, headers = user_agent)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    results = soup.find('tbody')
    summoners = results.find_all('tr')
    for i in range(len(summoners)):
      name = summoners[i].find('strong')
      summoners_listed.append(name.string)
    
  stop = timeit.default_timer()

  print('Time: ', stop - start)
  return summoners_listed
```

Comment: When i run into this problem, I usually create interim data frames and save them as a csv in a directory, then collect all of the DFs and concat them

Comment: I'm trying it out right now. I'll update in a few hours

Comment: It worked! I'll post the solution as a question. Thank you @1extralime

Answer (score 2):

Credit to @1extralime

All I did was make a csv for every page instead of continually appending to one super long list.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import timeit
import pandas as pd

def lol_scrape():
  start = timeit.default_timer()

  for i in range(6500):
    # Moved variable inside loop to reset it every iteration
    summoners_listed = []
    URL = "https://www.op.gg/leaderboards/tier?region=na&page="+str(i+1)
    user_agent = {user-agent}
    page = requests.get(URL, headers = user_agent)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    results = soup.find('tbody')
    summoners = results.find_all('tr')
    for x in range(len(summoners)):
      name = summoners[x].find('strong')
      summoners_listed.append(name.string)
    
    # Make a new df with the list values then save to a new csv
    df = pd.DataFrame(summoners_listed)
    df.to_csv('all_summoners/summoners_page'+str(i+1))  
    
  stop = timeit.default_timer()

  print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

Also as a note to my future self or anyone else reading. This method is way superior because had the process failed at anytime I had all the successful csv's saved and could just restart where it left off.

Comment: A message to your future self: use a database for such jobs, and async them. Note to your present self: congrats for a job done.